# How to 'Group By' date in SQL

Tags: sql

My data has 2 columns,

```
  Time                   | Name
  -----------------------+-----
  6/9/2020 7:40:31 PM    | A
  6/9/2020 7:52:51 PM    | B
  6/9/2020 8:31:03 PM    | C
  6/10/2020 9:21:00 PM   | A
  6/11/2020 12:08:06 PM  | A
```

How can I aggregate the data so that I can count how many entry per day (not to second of the date)
 something like:

```
  Time        | Count
  ------------+------
  6/9/2020    | 3
  6/10/2020   | 1
  6/11/2020   | 1
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Post the database engine name (version would also help) and also your table structure (e.g. the `CREATE` scripts), so we can provide better answers.

Comment: Standard SQL: `cast(timestamp_column as date)`

Comment: @dnoeth It would actually not work in Oracle, as in Oracle, the `DATE` type also contains time (up to seconds), but it's usually a good bet for many SQL engines.

Comment: @Hilarion: That's why I wrote *Standard SQL* :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to strip off the time. In SQL Server it would look like this.

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATE, Time) as [Time], COUNT(*)
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY CONVERT(DATE, Time)
```

Answer (score 0):

For Oracle:
`select to_char(Time, 'MM/DD/YYYY'), count from <table> group by to_char(Time, 'MM/DD/YYYY');`

Comment: Why would you convert date to text? Date without a time portion is still a date and there's no reason to convert it to text, just to group by days.

Comment: The date will grouped by seconds not by day

Comment: Nope. You just need to strip the time portion (that's why I wrote "date without a time portion"), no need to do this by converting to text.

Comment: Which Database you use?

Comment: I'm commenting on your answer, so I'm referring to Oracle DB. See my answer to this same question - it is for Oracle too.

Comment: It is very dangers to use Trunc in this kind on Oracle. And why you don't want to use to_char is fast and clean.

Comment: Could you share on what's dangerous about `TRUNC`? I'd also gladly see performance comparisons for `TO_CHAR` against `TRUNC`. I'm quite sure that `TO_CHAR` conversions are actually quite expensive (topped only by "from text" conversions/parses, at least in the single-valued functions world).

Answer (score 0):

You have not specified which database engine you are using and what data types you are using. (Are your date/time columns actually date/time, or maybe text?)

Assuming you are using Oracle and the `Time` column is of type `DATE`, the solution could be:

```sql
SELECT TRUNC("Time") AS "Time", COUNT(*) AS "Count"
  FROM SomeTable
 GROUP BY TRUNC("Time")
```